# AKFrequencyTracker with tempo

Tags: audiokit, frequency-analysis

When using AKFrequencyTracker, I like to add the "tempo" feature to recognize notes according to their pace and wonder

Trying to use AKPeriodicFunction and AKMetronome but it looks they are used for playback rather than analysis.

```
tracker = AKFrequencyTracker(mic)
if tracker.amplitude > 0.1 {
    var frequency = Float(tracker.frequency)
    ...
```

How can I add the "tempo" feature into the the tracker?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AudioKit doesn't have beat detection, which would be the first tempo to a tempo tracker. We recently incorporated Aubio with AudioKit for a client project:

https://github.com/aubio/aubio

There are other open source alternatives, just do some Google searches for "tempo detection GitHub":

https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=tempo+detection+github&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8